# Python TypeError: expected string or buffer. Need the response in dictionary

Tags: python, json, rest, response, python-requests

I have the following code

```
import requests
import sys
import json

arg_count = 0

#check that correct number of arguments are passed to utility
for arg in sys.argv:
    arg_count = arg_count + 1

assert arg_count == 4

#parse the input arguments to the utility
connectplus_group_title = sys.argv[1]
connectplus_uname = sys.argv[2]
connectplus_passwords = sys.argv[3]

#find the group id from the input group name i.e connectplus_group_title
response = requests.get("https://connectplus.geometricglobal.com/_vti_bin/beezy/v2/api.svc//Groups/Availability?title={title})", auth=(connectplus_uname, connectplus_passwords))
#assert response.status_code == response.codes.ok
group_data = json.loads(response)
group_id = group_data[connectplus_group_title]

connectplus_group_contributors = "https://connectplus.geometricglobal.com/_vti_bin/beezy/v2/api.svc//Groups/{id}/Contributors?skip={skip}&take={take}"
response = requests.get(connectplus_group_contributors,auth=(connectplus_uname, connectplus_passwords))
data = response.json()
```

I need to get the `json` data which is returned by the `URL` , I have tried using `json.loads(response.text)` or simple `json.loads(response)` with no luck I keep getting the above error.

What is the correct way to get the data from a `REST` url in the from of dictionary.

Comment: That error usually indicates malformed JSON. Can you post an exmaple of the JSON you are getting?

Comment: Exactly *where* do you get that error? Post the full traceback.

Comment: In response I am getting `401` , the web url requires authentication.

Comment: so you are not authorized... and response is not a json but maybe html containing an error page

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass `response.content`, **response** is a `Response` type not a simple string (try `type(response)`) and `json.loads` needs (as the error highlights) a string or buffer.

Replace your call with:

```
json.loads(response.content)
```

Comment: will the return objects is of type dictionary now.